# URL is invalid. It may refer to nonexistent file

Tags: sharepoint-server

Had seen similar post but I think SP raise the error broadly.
Tried work around / solution from other post but its not going anywhere.

We are branding master page and css file in fresh server when the error pops up. Tried to restore working backup and for some point it end on same error.

Done checking database files:

SQL SERVER 2012

wss_content: 42GB
wss_content_log: 4GB

sharepoint_config: 325MB
sharepoint_config_log:  784KB

There is no issue checking in/out file and even creating a fresh one. Then error trigger when the file get updated.

Tried iisreset, clear SPD cache and delete GUID files... wit ends.

[image]

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Arithmetic overflow error for data type smallint, value = 32768.     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreResults(Boolean& moreResults)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryNextResult(Boolean& more)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader....   00ca419d-439a-c0b3-7cbc-50b4757ee851

Comment: Is there any user control referred in master page.Check the url of that if there is

Comment: There is vs web parts but nothing was updated in master page and control itself. Mainly we are dealing with CSS file when error trigger. Tried restoring full content backup, in 4-5 saving (with minor css or html element change) it all end in same error.

Comment: Please get log entries from the ULS log when you attempt to save the file.

Comment: Hi, ULS log added. This is recurring message I notice when error encountered.

       "SQL error code from last error 220 - Arithmetic overflow error for data type smallint, value = 32768."

Comment: @TrevorSeward added ULS log error. Any idea will appreciate.

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide the text of the query itself (should be above that ULS entry) or simply upload the ULS log itself (may contain PII) somewhere for review?

Comment: The error was resolved by installing CU updates... at least till July 2015.